# onClickListener not working on navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to set an OnClickListener on the navigation drawer item , but I can't seem to get around.On clicking an item from the drawer a new intent should open.
I even tried to follow this video step by step still the problem is there.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M_4Oh2FeRYs

I am new to android so I can't seem to find the bug.

Here is my java code:

```html
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private NavigationView navView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        gv = findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        //Drawer
        DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close);
        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
        mToggle.syncState();
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        navView = findViewById(R.id.navView);
        navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    }
  
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
        else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.nav2:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "nav1 selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, new.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;

            case R.id.nav1:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "nav2 selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent j = new Intent(MainActivity.this, new.class);
                startActivity(j);
                break;
        }
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;

    }

}
```

here is the navigation_menu layout file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav1"
        android:title="@string/nav1"
        android:icon="@mipmap/nav2"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav2"
        android:title="@string/nav2"
        android:icon="@mipmap/nav1"/>
</menu>
```

here is the mainactivity.xml:

```html
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
    tools:context="com.example.xxx.xxx.MainActivity"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehaviour">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ffff"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.xxx.xxx.MainActivity"
    android:isScrollContainer="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:background="#ff77"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/banner1"
            android:src="@drawable/banner1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"/>
    </LinearLayout
        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#ffff"
            android:numColumns="3"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="2dp">
        </GridView>
</LinearLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navView"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:alpha="0.4"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I needed to put rest of the layout in a FrameLayout , this link helped.

https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer

So just needed to change the code of mainactivity.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
    tools:context="com.example.xxx.xxx.MainActivity"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehaviour">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ffff"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.xxx.xxx.MainActivity"
    android:isScrollContainer="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:background="#ff77"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/banner1"
            android:src="@drawable/banner1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"/>
    </LinearLayout
        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#ffff"
            android:numColumns="3"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="2dp">
        </GridView>
</LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navView"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:alpha="0.4"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private NavigationView navView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //Drawer
    mDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,R.string.navigation_drawer_open,R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();
//        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
    else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id) {
        case R.id.nav_camera:
            Toast.makeText(Main.this, "nav1 selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(Main.this, test.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;

        case R.id.nav_gallery:
          /*  Toast.makeText(Main.this, "nav2 selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent j = new Intent(Main.this, new.class);
            startActivity(j);*/
            break;
    }
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;

}

}
```

working for me 
or 
GO to File > new > Activity(last part) > Navigation Drawer Activity
which will add a navigation drawer class to your project